# How can I use powershell to call SHGetKnownFolderPath?

Tags: powershell, known-folders

I'm a total noob on windows powershell.
How can I use psl to call SHGetKnownFolderPath ?
I want to then also call SHSetKnownFolderPath if I dont like some of the values back from Get call.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use P/Invoke. Lee Holmes has an example of how to do this from PowerShell [here](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2009/01/19/powershell-pinvoke-walkthrough/). There's an example of how to use `SHGetKnownFolderPoath` [here](http://powershell.com/cs/forums/t/7707.aspx).

Alternatively, you might just be able to use `Environment.GetFolderPath`:

```
PS> [Environment]::GetFolderPath('CommonApplicationData')
C:\ProgramData
```

You can get the list of available options by the following:

```
PS> [Enum]::GetNames([Environment+SpecialFolder])
```

Comment: I tried using PInvoke in a ps1 script and got policy not allowed message. Perhaps a small c#/vb program would work. Or is there a power tweak tool that allows setting of those Explorer paths?

Comment: Did you use `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` first?

Comment: get-executionpolicy returns Restricted.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function you can use that will use SHGetKnownFolderPath to convert a well-known folder guid to its current path:

```
Function GetKnownFolder([string]$KnownFolderCLSID) {
  $KnownFolderCLSID = $KnownFolderCLSID.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "")
  $GetSignature = @'
    [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]public extern static int SHGetKnownFolderPath(
    ref Guid folderId, 
    uint flags, 
    IntPtr token,
    out IntPtr pszProfilePath);
'@
  $GetType = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $GetSignature -Name 'GetKnownFolders' -Namespace 'SHGetKnownFolderPath' -Using "System.Text" -PassThru -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  $ptr = [intptr]::Zero
  [void]$GetType::SHGetKnownFolderPath([Ref]"$KnownFolderCLSID", 0, 0, [ref]$ptr)
  $result = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringUni($ptr)
  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::FreeCoTaskMem($ptr)
  return $result
}
```

Usage example:

```
GetKnownFolder "C4AA340D-F20F-4863-AFEF-F87EF2E6BA25"
```

Will return

```
C:\Users\Public\Desktop
```

Reference for Well-Known folder GUID's can be found at [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/known-folder-guids-for-file-dialog-custom-places?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

Before you delve into static methods in the Framework, look at the variables in the `Env:` `PSDrive`.

`get-childitem env:`

`(get-item env:\CommonProgramFiles).Value`

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Tutorial](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/74942-move-location-pictures-folder-windows-10-a.html) (and others) the settings are in the registry:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders]
```

Those are an easy read in *powershell*, access them as a drive:

```
ps> cd hkcu:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\
ps> dir
```

And use the standard *powershell* tools to read these settings.

*NOTE: You can set them with powershell here however that might ruin your day.*

If you use the explorer to change the directory, it also moves the directory and stores the settings on multiple locations, like both 'User Shell Folders' and 'Shell Folders'.